# After one failed CORS request, browser stops trying?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors

I'm using a Javascript library (StropheJS, specifically) that makes a series of repeated Ajax requests to a certain resource. These requests meet the criteria for a "simple" (ie non-preflight) CORS request: that is, the request method is `POST` and the Content-type is `text/plain`.

I've noticed that in one particular case (due to a misconfiguration on my side, not really what my question is about) the server responds without the required `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header. The Javascript code of course does not see that response, that's expected. My question is this: it appears that once this happens, all subsequent requests to that same cross-origin resource also fail instantly and the browser doesn't even attempt to actually make the network request, and this continues until I unload the current document. Is this expected behavior? If so, why?

Comment: Did this happen cross browser, or for one in particular?

Comment: It was reported in Chrome, I don't recall it in others.